# injected instance variables are null on aspect execution

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have this odd problem with Spring AOP and I am hoping someone can shed some light on it.

I am using CGLIB proxies and when I execute the following aspect i get a null pointer:

```
@Aspect
@Component //i.e. Singleton
public class MyAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAspect.class);

    {

        logger.debug("new instance of MyAspect");  //Line 1
    }

    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory;

    @Inject
    public MyAspect(AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory) {

        if (factory ==null) {

            logger.debug("your factory is null");  //Line 2
        } else {

            logger.debug("your factory is not null");
        }
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(com.domain.annotations.MyAnnotation)")
    public void doSomething() {

        if (factory ==null) {

            logger.debug("your factory is null again");  //Line 3
        }

                    // this is a request scoped bean
        MyRequest request = factory.getBean(MyRequest.class);  //Line 4



        if (request != null) {
            logger.debug("No");
            }
        else {
            logger.debug("Yes");
            }
    }
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException at Line 4.  I can see that the "factory" is null at Line 3 but it is not null when the instance is create at Line 2.  I am also tracking the instances being created at Line 1.

This design works using interfaces (JDK dynamic proxies). Why do my instances variables become null at runtime and is there a work around to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long and short is that you can't use Spring's constructer based injection with Aspects. There's a good forum discussion on this topic [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?79674-Spring-with-AspectJ-Load-Time-Weaving).

I personally use property-based injection for my aspects as suggested in the above forum. The example below allows you to inject a service into an auditing aspect. You don't need any additional XML configuration, as long as you make your aspect implement ApplicationContextAware.

```
@Aspect
@Component("auditAspect")
public class AuditAspect implements ApplicationContextAware {

ApplicationContext context;

public Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    // do stuff with context here
}

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;       
 }
```

Comment: thanks Filip...I have tried property injections AND method injections to set this property, but it still doesnt work. something like:

     @Inject private AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory;

Comment: Have you used the XML declaration above? I'm not sure if you can specify the factory-method property using only annotations.

Comment: im trying the xml version out... im having trouble getting an instance of AutowireCapableBeanFactory in the xml config using your example.  most of my beans are config-ed by annotations.  any examples would help.

Comment: To me, it seems like the method cannot access its own instance variables at all.  For example, I changed the aspect to be ApplicationContextAware (manually setting the property, not using injection), and I get the same results (null factory in method).  Also, changing the property to a "static" variable fixes it.  This is fine temporarily but to me that would be bad design.

Comment: I'm able to get it working by implementing ApplicationContextAware, as described above.

Comment: @phife757 is right. See the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633840/spring-autowired-bean-for-aspect-aspect-is-null for an explanation