# Spring Boot AOP load time weaving

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-boot, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

Not sure what is going wrong, but AOP just doesn't seem to be working in my setup with spring boot (v1.1.6).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCaching
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And in the aspect class

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(private * com.myapp.service.MyService.test(..)) && args(str1,str2)", argNames = "str1,str2")
    public void advice(String str1, String str2) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Advising after returning");
    }
}
```

In the service class that needs the advice

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  public void test(String str1, String str2) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Test method in service");
    //rest of the implementation
  }
}
```

I also have a META-INF/aop.xml like so

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.myapp.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="com.myapp.aspect.MyAspect"/>
    </aspects>

</aspectj>
```

When I run the application with -javaagent:path/to/spring-instrument-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar

I get this message on the console

```
2014-09-05 08:42:12.500  INFO 65053 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
2014-09-05 08:42:13.114  INFO 65053 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-09-05 08:42:13.156  INFO 65053 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter      : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementServerProperties$Security
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementServerProperties$Security
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Nothing happens with the advice though. It won't fire.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In order to advise private methods you need to use a ***privileged*** aspect:

```java
public privileged aspect MyAspect {
    // ...
}
```

But the [AspectJ documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspects.html) says:

> **Limitations:** Privileged aspects are not supported by the annotation style.

So please use native syntax, not @AspectJ style. Before you do that, though, test if non-privileged, annotation-style aspects work as expected with public methods in order to exclude other reasons for your aspects being woven.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I had to annotate my aspect class with the annotation @Component.

```
 @Aspect
 @Component
 public class MyAspect {
     ...
 }
```

The following link has a spring boot AOP example that helped me

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-aop

Answer (score 1):

Add below changes to your code and it should work. Do not need to create aop.xml. These changes will add the aspect to container and also weave it.

Read -- [Enable Spring AOP or AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666922/enable-spring-aop-or-aspectj)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCaching
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy -- Use this instead of @EnableLoadTimeWeaving

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Aspect
 @Component/@Configurable -- Both of them work
 public class MyAspect {
     ...
 }
```